# bottom navigation setupWithNavController doesnt work

Tags: android, kotlin

I Use Navigation Components.
I Have A Bottom Navigation And I Want To Switch Between Fragments. But When I Use setupWithNavController Method , Nothing Happens.
Even The Navigation Options Doesn't Change.
setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener Method Works Correctly But I Want To Know What Is My Problem.

Here Is activity_main.xml

```
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph = "@navigation/nav_home"
    />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    />
```

MainActivity class :

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController
        appBarConfiguration =
            AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.bottomNavFragment, R.id.infoFragment))

        val bottomNav = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        bottomNav.setupWithNavController( navController);

    }
}
```

navigation :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    app:startDestination="@id/bottomNavFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavFragment"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavtestproject.BlankFragment1"
        android:label="Home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank1" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/infoFragment"
        android:name="com.example.bottomnavtestproject.BlankFragment2"
        android:label="Info"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank2" />
</navigation>
```

menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_24"
        android:title="Favorite"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        android:title="Home"/>
```

build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bottomnavtest"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    def fragment_version = "1.3.1"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"


    def nav_version = "2.3.3"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    // Feature module Support
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

    // Testing Navigation
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"



}
```

Answer (score 3):

set menu items id's same as in navigation fragments id

For example if in your navigation fragment id `android:id="@+id/bottomNavFragment"`

In menu xml file item id should be the same, like:

```
<item android:id="@+id/bottomNavFragment"...
```